# ASP.NET MVC3 Html.Raw, Html.Encode NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a little problem. I use ASP.NET MVC 3 on Visual Web developer express and when i use **Html.Raw** or **Html.Encode** in razor view or helper, i get a NullReferenceException à runtime.

for exemple :

```
@Html.Raw(post.Body)
```

or other

```
@Html.Raw(@Html.Encode(comment.Body).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
```

However, strings are not empty. For exemple, to bypass the first case, i used

```
@(new HtmlString(post.Body))
```

But i would understand why it does not work with Html;Raw and Html.Encode, instead try hack.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think post is null

Comment: or Body ... Can't you put a breakpoint on one of those lines and see which object is null?

Comment: Did you try @{Html.Raw(post.Body)}?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem. I work in a Helper who take as argument an HtmlHelper

```
@helper Render(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, ...
```

Instead of calling html argument, i called Html object who wasn't instanciate. For resume, instead of

```
@Html.Raw(...)
```

I do :

```
@html.Raw(...)
```

Thanks for your answers.